# Pass a whole object to redux reselect selector, but change it only if one property of the object changes

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, reselect

Started working with `Reselect` and there's one thing I can't seem to find an answer for.

Say I have a helper fn (`getVehicleList`) which does some heavy calculations, so I don't want it to re-run too much. I use state selectors to get the properties I need, something like:

```
const getVehicles = (state) => state.vehicles.vehicles;
const getVehicle = (state) => state.vehicles.vehicle;
const getUserId = (state) => state.auth.user.id;
```

I then have implemented the `createSelector`:

```
const getVehicles = createSelector(
  [getVehicles,
   getVehicle,
   getUserId],
  (vehicles, vehicle, id) => getVehicleList(
    vehicles,
    vehicle,
    id,
  ),
);
```

Now, `vehicle` returns an object with multiple fields. If any of these fields change, the object changes and so everything is recomputed again. Is there a way to stop this recomputing until the `id` and only the id of the vehicle changes?

I tried doing a state selector for the id, like

```
const getVehicle = (state) => state.vehicles.vehicle.id;
```

But that doesn't work for me, cause I need the whole vehicle object inside my helper fn and not just the id.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
const getVehicles = (state) => state.vehicles.vehicles;
const getVehicle = (state) => state.vehicles.vehicle;
const getUserId = (state) => state.auth.user.id;
const selectVhicleId = createSelector(
  [getVehicle],
  ({ id }) => id //return only the id
);
const selectVehicles = createSelector(
  [getVehicles, selectVhicleId, getUserId],
  (vehicles, vehicleId, id) =>
    getVehicleList(vehicles, { id: vehicleId }, id)
);
```

[Here](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/selectors) is some information about how I use reselect with React.

Here is an example that re calculate vehicles when vehicle.id changes (or any of the other dependencies). It will not re calculate if other values of vehicle change so the vehicle used getVehicleList gets a stale vehicle passed to it that is only refreshed when vehicle.id changes:

```
const getVehicles = (state) => state.vehicles.vehicles;
const getVehicle = (state) => state.vehicles.vehicle;
const getUserId = (state) => state.auth.user.id;
const createSelectVehicles = (vehicle) =>
  createSelector([getVehicles, getUserId], (vehicles, id) =>
    getVehicleList(vehicles, vehicle, id)
  );

const Component = () => {
  //only re calculate vehicle if vehicle.id changes
  const vehicle = useSelector(
    getVehicle,
    (a, b) => a?.id === b?.id
  );
  //only create the selector when vehicle changes
  //  vehicle only changes when vehicle.id changes
  const selectVehicles = React.useMemo(
    () => createSelectVehicles(vehicle),
    [vehicle]
  );
  //vehicles is re calculated when vehicle.id changes
  //  or when state.vehicles.vehicles changes or
  //  when state.auth.user.id changes
  const vehicles = useSelector(selectVehicles);
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but if I understand correctly, in this case in the `selectVehicles` selector I will have only the `id` of the vehicle that I can use in the getVehicleList fn, and I need the whole vehicle object. 


I will check out the link, but I suppose that due to immutability concerns, it's actually better to rerun the memoization if any of the properties of the object changes, so not sure it's possible to do what I have in mind.

Comment: @Konstantin You are not making any sense: `I need the whole vehicle object.` and `Is there a way to stop this recomputing until the id and only the id of the vehicle changes?` If you only re compute when id changes then why you need the whole vehicle? If any of the other `whole vehicle` fields change you don't re compute and your UI will not reflect those changes yet you claim you do neet it.

Comment: I was hoping to achieve some kind of `useEffect` dep array functionality, where I'm able to pass just one property of the object and re-run calculations when just that property changes, although the whole object is included. I do need it in the fn because I add it to my array of vehicles. I now see that it doesn't make that much sense and it's much better to have the object from Redux as is, and stop memoization when the object reference changes. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: @Konstantin I updated my answer with an example that will get a stale vehicle passed to getVehicleList that only refreshes when vehicle.id changes. Not sure if the outcome is useful because the vehicle that is passed may not have the updated fields you need.

Comment: Got you, thank you a lot, I've also checked out the link and have gathered a couple of ideas from there, thanks for the help once again!